# I2C communication error: OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error while using PAJ7620 sensor

Tags: networking, hardware, i2c, raspberry-pi-os, micropython

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times. But, none of the answers was able to resolve my problem... I'm hoping I could get some guidence from awesome people in this community. Thanks in advance for taking time in answering and for reading this long question !!

**Problem:** OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O while running PAJ_sample_new.py

**Context:** I'm trying to establish I2C communication with PAJ7620 gesture sensor with RPi 4 model B with the help of smbus2 library. I modified [Grove Gesture Sensor (PAJ7620) code available on github](https://github.com/rafi021/Pycom-module-Example/blob/master/Grove%20Gesture%20Sensor/main.py). I removed the dependency of [MicroPython - Machine library.](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-infineon/blob/master/docs/library/machine.I2C.rst)  and replaced with [smbus2 library](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/).

**Already tried:**

- I [configured my RPi for I2C comm.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi/configuring-your-pi-for-i2c) and detected my PAJ7620 (with 0x73 address), in Bus 1.
- Connections between the SDA and SCL pins of RPi and PAJ7620 has been done properly and carefully.
- Soldered the header pins to PAJ7620. And did check for countinuity using a digital multimeter.
- Both the files are in the same directory.

**Screenshot of Error:**

- [image]

**Code :**

PAJ_sample_new.py

```
#from machine import I2C
#from pycom import *
#import color
from time import sleep
from gesture_new import Gesture
#i2c=I2C(0,I2C.MASTER)
#<g=Gesture(i2c)>
g=Gesture()
i=0
# heartbeat(False)
#   0:nothing  ->Black
#   1:Forward  -> Red
#   2:Backward -> Green
#   3:Right    -> Yellow
#   4:Left     -> Blue
#   5:Up       -> White
#   6:Down     -> Aqua
#   7:Clockwise -> Magenta
#   8:anti-clockwise -> Mix Green|Red
#   9:wave           -> Mix Green| Blue
while (i<10):
    g.print_gesture()
    value=g.return_gesture()
    print(value)
    if value==0:
        print('nothing')# rgbled(color.Black)   # nothing
    if value==1: print('Forward') # rgbled(color.Green)   # Forward 
    if value==2: print('Backward') #rgbled(color.Red)     # Backward
    if value==3: print('Right')#rgbled(color.Yellow)  # Right
    if value==4: print('Left')  # rgbled(color.Blue)    # Left
    if value==5: print('UP')#rgbled(color.White)   # Up
    if value==6: print('Down')#rgbled(color.Aqua)    # Down
    if value==7: print('Clockwise')#rgbled(color.Magenta) # Clockwise
    if value==8: print('anti-Clockwise')#rgbled(color.Green|color.Red) # anti-clockwise
    if value==9:print('wave')#rgbled(color.Green|color.Blue) # Wave
    i=i+1
    sleep(1)
```

gesture_new.py

```
import time
#import machine
from smbus2 import SMBus

#Registers and variables for the gesture sensor
GES_REACTION_TIME=0.5 # You can adjust the reaction time according to the actual circumstance.
GES_ENTRY_TIME   =0.8    # When you want to recognize the Forward/Backward gestures, your gestures' reaction time must less than GES_ENTRY_TIME(0.8s).
GES_QUIT_TIME    =1.0

BANK0 = 0
BANK1 = 1

PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE=0x00
#REGISTER BANK SELECT
PAJ7620_REGITER_BANK_SEL =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0xEF)    #W
#DEVICE ID
PAJ7620_ID=0x73

#REGISTER BANK 0
PAJ7620_ADDR_SUSPEND_CMD        =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x3)  #W
PAJ7620_ADDR_GES_PS_DET_MASK_0  =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x41) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_GES_PS_DET_MASK_1  =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x42) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_GES_PS_DET_FLAG_0  =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x43) #R
PAJ7620_ADDR_GES_PS_DET_FLAG_1  =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x44) #R
PAJ7620_ADDR_STATE_INDICATOR    =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x45) #R
PAJ7620_ADDR_PS_HIGH_THRESHOLD  =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x69) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_PS_LOW_THRESHOLD   =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6A) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_PS_APPROACH_STATE  =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6B) #R
PAJ7620_ADDR_PS_RAW_DATA        =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6C) #R

#REGISTER BANK 1
PAJ7620_ADDR_PS_GAIN            =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x44) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_IDLE_S1_STEP_0     =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x67) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_IDLE_S1_STEP_1     =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x68) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_IDLE_S2_STEP_0     =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x69) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_IDLE_S2_STEP_1     =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6A) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_OP_TO_S1_STEP_0    =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6B) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_OP_TO_S1_STEP_1    =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6C) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_OP_TO_S2_STEP_0    =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6D) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_OP_TO_S2_STEP_1    =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x6E) #RW
PAJ7620_ADDR_OPERATION_ENABLE   =(PAJ7620_ADDR_BASE + 0x72) #RW

#PAJ7620_REGITER_BANK_SEL
PAJ7620_BANK0=0
PAJ7620_BANK1=1

#PAJ7620_ADDR_SUSPEND_CMD
PAJ7620_I2C_WAKEUP  =1
PAJ7620_I2C_SUSPEND =0

#PAJ7620_ADDR_OPERATION_ENABLE
PAJ7620_ENABLE=1
PAJ7620_DISABLE=0

#ADC, delete
REG_ADDR_RESULT = 0x00
REG_ADDR_ALERT  = 0x01
REG_ADDR_CONFIG = 0x02
REG_ADDR_LIMITL = 0x03
REG_ADDR_LIMITH = 0x04
REG_ADDR_HYST   = 0x05
REG_ADDR_CONVL  = 0x06
REG_ADDR_CONVH  = 0x07

GES_RIGHT_FLAG           =1<<0
GES_LEFT_FLAG            =1<<1
GES_UP_FLAG              =1<<2
GES_DOWN_FLAG            =1<<3
GES_FORWARD_FLAG         =1<<4
GES_BACKWARD_FLAG        =1<<5
GES_CLOCKWISE_FLAG       =1<<6
GES_COUNT_CLOCKWISE_FLAG =1<<7
GES_WAVE_FLAG            =1<<0

#Gesture output
FORWARD         = 1
BACKWARD        = 2
RIGHT           = 3
LEFT            = 4
UP              = 5
DOWN            = 6
CLOCKWISE       = 7
ANTI_CLOCKWISE  = 8
WAVE            = 9

#Initial register state
initRegisterArray=( [0xEF,0x00],[0x32,0x29],[0x33,0x01],[0x34,0x00],[0x35,0x01],[0x36,0x00],
[0x37,0x07],[0x38,0x17],[0x39,0x06],[0x3A,0x12],[0x3F,0x00],[0x40,0x02],[0x41,0xFF],[0x42,0x01],
[0x46,0x2D],[0x47,0x0F],[0x48,0x3C],[0x49,0x00],[0x4A,0x1E],[0x4B,0x00],[0x4C,0x20],[0x4D,0x00],
[0x4E,0x1A],[0x4F,0x14],[0x50,0x00],[0x51,0x10],[0x52,0x00],[0x5C,0x02],[0x5D,0x00],[0x5E,0x10],
[0x5F,0x3F],[0x60,0x27],[0x61,0x28],[0x62,0x00],[0x63,0x03],[0x64,0xF7],[0x65,0x03],[0x66,0xD9],
[0x67,0x03],[0x68,0x01],[0x69,0xC8],[0x6A,0x40],[0x6D,0x04],[0x6E,0x00],[0x6F,0x00],[0x70,0x80],
[0x71,0x00],[0x72,0x00],[0x73,0x00],[0x74,0xF0],[0x75,0x00],[0x80,0x42],[0x81,0x44],[0x82,0x04],
[0x83,0x20],[0x84,0x20],[0x85,0x00],[0x86,0x10],[0x87,0x00],[0x88,0x05],[0x89,0x18],[0x8A,0x10],
[0x8B,0x01],[0x8C,0x37],[0x8D,0x00],[0x8E,0xF0],[0x8F,0x81],[0x90,0x06],[0x91,0x06],[0x92,0x1E],
[0x93,0x0D],[0x94,0x0A],[0x95,0x0A],[0x96,0x0C],[0x97,0x05],[0x98,0x0A],[0x99,0x41],[0x9A,0x14],
[0x9B,0x0A],[0x9C,0x3F],[0x9D,0x33],[0x9E,0xAE],[0x9F,0xF9],[0xA0,0x48],[0xA1,0x13],[0xA2,0x10],
[0xA3,0x08],[0xA4,0x30],[0xA5,0x19],[0xA6,0x10],[0xA7,0x08],[0xA8,0x24],[0xA9,0x04],[0xAA,0x1E],
[0xAB,0x1E],[0xCC,0x19],[0xCD,0x0B],[0xCE,0x13],[0xCF,0x64],[0xD0,0x21],[0xD1,0x0F],[0xD2,0x88],
[0xE0,0x01],[0xE1,0x04],[0xE2,0x41],[0xE3,0xD6],[0xE4,0x00],[0xE5,0x0C],[0xE6,0x0A],[0xE7,0x00],
[0xE8,0x00],[0xE9,0x00],[0xEE,0x07],[0xEF,0x01],[0x00,0x1E],[0x01,0x1E],[0x02,0x0F],[0x03,0x10],
[0x04,0x02],[0x05,0x00],[0x06,0xB0],[0x07,0x04],[0x08,0x0D],[0x09,0x0E],[0x0A,0x9C],[0x0B,0x04],
[0x0C,0x05],[0x0D,0x0F],[0x0E,0x02],[0x0F,0x12],[0x10,0x02],[0x11,0x02],[0x12,0x00],[0x13,0x01],
[0x14,0x05],[0x15,0x07],[0x16,0x05],[0x17,0x07],[0x18,0x01],[0x19,0x04],[0x1A,0x05],[0x1B,0x0C],
[0x1C,0x2A],[0x1D,0x01],[0x1E,0x00],[0x21,0x00],[0x22,0x00],[0x23,0x00],[0x25,0x01],[0x26,0x00],
[0x27,0x39],[0x28,0x7F],[0x29,0x08],[0x30,0x03],[0x31,0x00],[0x32,0x1A],[0x33,0x1A],[0x34,0x07],
[0x35,0x07],[0x36,0x01],[0x37,0xFF],[0x38,0x36],[0x39,0x07],[0x3A,0x00],[0x3E,0xFF],[0x3F,0x00],
[0x40,0x77],[0x41,0x40],[0x42,0x00],[0x43,0x30],[0x44,0xA0],[0x45,0x5C],[0x46,0x00],[0x47,0x00],
[0x48,0x58],[0x4A,0x1E],[0x4B,0x1E],[0x4C,0x00],[0x4D,0x00],[0x4E,0xA0],[0x4F,0x80],[0x50,0x00],
[0x51,0x00],[0x52,0x00],[0x53,0x00],[0x54,0x00],[0x57,0x80],[0x59,0x10],[0x5A,0x08],[0x5B,0x94],
[0x5C,0xE8],[0x5D,0x08],[0x5E,0x3D],[0x5F,0x99],[0x60,0x45],[0x61,0x40],[0x63,0x2D],[0x64,0x02],
[0x65,0x96],[0x66,0x00],[0x67,0x97],[0x68,0x01],[0x69,0xCD],[0x6A,0x01],[0x6B,0xB0],[0x6C,0x04],
[0x6D,0x2C],[0x6E,0x01],[0x6F,0x32],[0x71,0x00],[0x72,0x01],[0x73,0x35],[0x74,0x00],[0x75,0x33],
[0x76,0x31],[0x77,0x01],[0x7C,0x84],[0x7D,0x03],[0x7E,0x01])


class Gesture():    #object
    """initialize the sensor"""
    def __init__(self, address=PAJ7620_ID):     #i2c=None
        #self.i2c = i2c
        self.address=address
        time.sleep(0.001)
        self.paj7620SelectBank(BANK0)
        self.paj7620SelectBank(BANK0)
        data0=self.paj7620ReadReg(0,1)[0]
        data1=self.paj7620ReadReg(1,1)[0]
        if data0!=0x20:
            print("Error with sensor")
        print("PAJ7620 initialize register finished")
        for i in range(len(initRegisterArray)):
            self.paj7620WriteReg(initRegisterArray[i][0],initRegisterArray[i][1])
        self.paj7620SelectBank(BANK0)

    # Write a byte to a register on the Gesture sensor
    def paj7620WriteReg(self,addr,cmd):
        buf=bytearray(1)
        buf[0]=cmd
        #self.i2c.writeto_mem(self.address,addr,buf)
        with SMBus(1) as bus: bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.address,addr,buf)
            # Write a block of 8 bytes to address 80 from offset 0
            # Select a register bank on the Gesture sensor
    def paj7620SelectBank(self,bank):
        if bank==BANK0:
            self.paj7620WriteReg(PAJ7620_REGITER_BANK_SEL,PAJ7620_BANK0)
    # Read a block of bytes of length "qty" starting at address "addr" from the Gesture sensor
    def paj7620ReadReg(self,addr,qty):
        with SMBus(1) as bus: block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr,self.address, qty)
            #return self.i2c.readfrom_mem(self.address,addr,qty)
            # Read a block of 16 bytes from address 80, offset
            
            # Returned value is a list of qty bytes
            #print(block)

    #Print the values from the gesture sensor
    def print_gesture(self):
        data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43,1)[0]
        if data==GES_RIGHT_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                print("Forward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                print("Backward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                print("Right")

        elif data==GES_LEFT_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                print("Forward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                print("Backward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                print("Left")

        elif data==GES_UP_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                print("Forward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                print("Backward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                print("Up")

        elif data==GES_DOWN_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                print("Forward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                print("Backward")
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                print("Down")

        elif data==GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
            print("Forward")
            time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)

        elif data==GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
            print("Backward")
            time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)

        elif data==GES_CLOCKWISE_FLAG:
            print("Clockwise")

        elif data==GES_COUNT_CLOCKWISE_FLAG:
            print("anti-clockwise")

        else:
            data1=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x44, 1)[0]
            if (data1 == GES_WAVE_FLAG):
                print("wave")
    #Return a vlaue from the gestire sensor which can be used in a program
    #   0:nothing
    #   1:Forward
    #   2:Backward
    #   3:Right
    #   4:Left
    #   5:Up
    #   6:Down
    #   7:Clockwise
    #   8:anti-clockwise
    #   9:wave
    def return_gesture(self):

        data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43,1)[0]
        if data==GES_RIGHT_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                return 1
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                return 2
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                return 3

        elif data==GES_LEFT_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                return 1
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                return 2
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                return 4

        elif data==GES_UP_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                return 1
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                return 2
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                return 5

        elif data==GES_DOWN_FLAG:
            time.sleep(GES_ENTRY_TIME)
            data=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x43, 1)[0]
            if data == GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
                return 1
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            elif data == GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
                return 2
                time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)
            else:
                return 6

        elif data==GES_FORWARD_FLAG:
            return 1
            time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)

        elif data==GES_BACKWARD_FLAG:
            return 2
            time.sleep(GES_QUIT_TIME)

        elif data==GES_CLOCKWISE_FLAG:
            return 7

        elif data==GES_COUNT_CLOCKWISE_FLAG:
            return 8

        else:
            data1=self.paj7620ReadReg(0x44, 1)[0]
            if (data1 == GES_WAVE_FLAG):
                return 9
        return 0
```

Comment: I suggest you prepare a simple smbus script just to read a register.  Check that works in a loop.  Also search "raspberry pi python smbus PAJ7620" to see if there is a better example to rejig.

Comment: I noticed that your Rpi4B are using "***block read***", which might be a root cause of problem. A quick and dirty check to confirm is ***Lower I2C speed to as low as 50kHz***". I once read that this workaround works for Rpi4 (smbus1, but not sure for smbus2).

Answer (score 1):

Errno 121 usually occurs when running an I2C python program with the following situation:

2.1 The hardware wiring connection is bad, eg,

```
2.1.1 Forget to plug/connect the cable,

2.1.2 Too long cabling, eg, over 30cm,

2.1.2 I2C frequency too high, over 400kHz,

2.1.3 I2C device, eg. I2C I2C MCP23017, which is sensitive to noise,

2.1.4 I2C bus overloaded, with more than 4 devices, causing bus capacitance over 400pF.
```